# ExtJS auto-resize form

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I'm using Extjs5 and I have a form where I wish it to be auto resize according to it's container.

Currently, I have:

container->items->layout:vbox->items->layout:{type:column,columns:2}->items->my forms(consist of comboboxes and textfields)

when I resize to a small width, I wish it to be one column. Currently it will remain 2 columns and the space will be too small to fit 2 column design. Is there a way to resize it to 1 column?

Comment: what will happen with that second column if you want to show only one?

Comment: @MaxDeepfield: Then in this case form will take its parent container's width.
user1679887: There no such config which will help you to achieve this.You will need to achieve this using custom form design.

Comment: @MaxDeepfield I was hoping that all the textfields and comboboxes are fit into 1 column in a vertical way. ie 1 component 1 row. Currently the two columns is that in a row, I have two components. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: @Tejas1991 I managed to find a way by using container->items->layout:{type:column,columns:2}->items->layout:{type:column,columns:1}->items->my forms(consist of comboboxes and textfields)->layout:{type:column,columns:1}->items->my forms(consist of comboboxes and textfields) but as u can see, my items were split into two list. If i hide a field from one of the list the arrangement in two columns would look weird, ie the left side might have less items than on the right

Comment: you can't change layout type in extjs, but you can try recreate containers (or make two of them, column and vbox, vbox is hidden until width is small enough, than switch visibility with items migration)

Comment: user: Please illustrate your ansewer using some fiddle

Comment: Can you put some code or give more information.

Comment: What you need is not a column layout with 2 columns, but a `hbox` layout containing two containers with `flex:1`. When the browser window becomes smaller, you can convert the hbox layout to a vbox layout using `setLayout({vertical:true})`, and when it becomes bigger again, you can convert it back by setting `vertical:false` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to achieve this with a `column` layout, you can listen for the `resize` event and adjust the column percentages in the handler function.  The handler function could look like:

```
formResize = function (item, width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight, eOpts) {
    if (!item.narrow) return;
    if (oldWidth === undefined) oldWidth = 9999999;
    if (oldHeight === undefined) oldHeight = 9999999;
    item.suspendLayouts();
    if (width <= item.narrow && oldWidth > item.narrow) {
        item.items.each(function (item, i) {
            if (!item.originalColumnWidth) item.originalColumnWidth = item.columnWidth;
            item.columnWidth = 1;
        });
    }
    if (width > item.narrow && oldWidth <= item.narrow) {
        item.items.each(function (item, i) {
            item.columnWidth = item.originalColumnWidth;
        });
    }
    item.resumeLayouts(true);
};
```

This requires a property called `narrow` to be defined on the panel that is being adjusted.  You could set narrow=700 to use a single column layout when the width is less than 700 and keep the original layout otherwise.  The originalColumnWidth is saved on the first execution so it can be restored if the form is resized to be wide enough for multiple columns.

[See fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1t5i) with an example form.

(A similar result can be achieved using the `responsive` plugin.  See [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1t5j)).

Comment: thanks I have implemented your way and it works. Thanks :)